# Same Rest Api returns Internal Server Error when using HttpClient

Tags: c#, rest, httpclient

I'm sending a PUT request to a Rest url. If I do the following it works:

```
var client = new HttpClient()
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(@"https://myip:myport/"),
};
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); 

using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, uri))
{
    request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myobject), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

However, if I do the following I get an `500 Internal Server Error`:

```
var client = new HttpClient()
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(@"https://myip:myport/"),
};
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); 

using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.PutAsJsonAsync(uri, myobject).Result)
{
    var r = response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

What might I be missing in the second snippet?

Comment: Is the called API endpoint allows a PUT method?

Comment: @Oluwafemi Yes. Because if not both methods will fail with a 405 Method Not Allowed.

Comment: Can you present us with the API methods signatures and attributes?